# Input Boost Low-Harmonic Rectifier

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, power-factor-correction

I have a question from Coursera,
Please see the below figure.
I don't understand what does question 13 means, could someone explain it to me?
When Vref2 increased by 4%, the output voltage doesn't change. I think this is very weird to me because the command becomes larger than the original, why is the output can maintain?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that the output voltage doesn't change when changing Vref2?

Comment: @JohnD every the else in the system remains the same

Comment: @JohnD Questio 13 said

Comment: I think the question is just poorly worded.  If EVERYTHING else remained the same then the  answer is trivial, Vcontrol doesn't change at all.  Vref2 is the reference for the outer voltage loop and therefore the output voltage must change when it changes.